# What is the locale name of utf16 encoding (English) in Windows 10?

Tags: c++, encoding, windows-10, locale

I was able to set std::locale to "en-US.UTF8" but I don't know the correct version of it for UTF16 encoding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to set UTF-16 as locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592540/unable-to-set-utf-16-as-locale)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328697/using-utf-16-for-i-o-with-visual-studio-instead-of-code-pages

Comment: If you are using Windows Win32, Victor's link has the answer (in particular, **phuclv**'s answer).  If you are using Windows WSL, Gandhi's link has the answer.

Comment: @Eljay _setmode accepts FILE* and cannot be used with std::wofstreams. It seems that there is no answer... even though Windows now natively uses UTF16 internally.